# Changed security permissions on external hard drive to a user with full control and now it will not allow me to backup it says

Tags: hard-drive, backup, permissions

I have changed the security permissions on an external hard drive to a username and allowed full control now when I try to do a windows backup I get this error:

[image: Access is denied (0x8007005)]

Can someone please let me know what I need to do to get this to allow me to backup to the external drive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On external drives in file permissions if you want to do a backup you can't only have the username selected in the permissions they have to be part of the administrator group, which means that this will not work to keep external drives encrypted for backups.

I will have to find another method to encrypt the external hard drive.

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 10 Pro and I am going to make a post on how to use bitlocker and file history soon.